# lots of errorrs when upgraded to react core to v8

Tags: wallet-connect

lots of errorrs when upgraded to react core to v8

"I am working on upgrading WalletConnect from v1 to v2, and I have installed the required packages. I also upgraded React core. However, I encountered several errors. Can you provide any solutions?"

Comment: come with a minimum reproducible example